# using OR operator in javascript switch statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

I'm doing a switch statement in javascript:

```
switch($tp_type){

    case 'ITP':
    $('#indv_tp_id').val(data);
    break;

     case 'CRP'||'COO'||'FOU':
    $('#jurd_tp_id').val(data);
    break;

}
```

But I think it doesn't work if I use OR operator. How do I properly do this in javascript?
If I choose ITP,I get ITP. But if I choose either COO, FOU OR CRP I always get the first one which is CRP. Please help, thanks!

Comment: See also [JavaScript or-expression in a switch case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513585/javascript-or-expression-in-a-switch-case).

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You should re-write it like this:

```
case 'CRP':
case 'COO':
case 'FOU':
  $('#jurd_tp_id').val(data);
  break;
```

You can see it documented in the [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) reference. The behavior of consecutive `case` statements without `break`s in between (called "fall-through") is described there:

> The optional break statement associated with each case label ensures that the program breaks out of switch once the matched statement is executed and continues execution at the statement following switch. *If break is omitted, the program continues execution at the next statement in the switch statement*.

As for why your version only works for the first item (`CRP`), it's simply because the expression `'CRP'||'COO'||'FOU'` evaluates to `'CRP'` (since non-empty strings evaluate to `true` in Boolean context). So that `case` statement is equivalent to just `case 'CRP':` once evaluated.

Comment: This is called "fall-through": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_case . Putting each `case` on a separate line makes it easier to read IMO.

Comment: is it possible to use calculations in a switch statement? for example, something like `case (expr / 2 < 10):` ??

Comment: @oldboy Switch statements aren't supposed to be this complex.  Just use `if` statements at that point.