# Test for multiple cases in a switch, like an OR (||)

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, fall-through

How would you use a `switch` `case` when you need to test for *a* **or** *b* in the same case?

```
switch (pageid) {
  case "listing-page":
  case "home-page":
    alert("hello");
    break;
  case "details-page":
    alert("goodbye");
    break;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [using OR operator in javascript switch statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476994/using-or-operator-in-javascript-switch-statement) -- it's 100% your question ;)

Comment: I found using commas only 2 options allowed each case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch statement for multiple cases in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207927/switch-statement-for-multiple-cases-in-javascript)

Answer (score 790, accepted):

You can use fall-through:

```
switch (pageid)
{
    case "listing-page":
    case "home-page":
        alert("hello");
        break;
    case "details-page":
        alert("goodbye");
        break;
}
```

Comment: I found this out before I posted the question, but thought it would be useful for the community since it's not well documented anywhere... thank you @SLaks for you're answer too.

Comment: Hi @kei I know this isn't the proper place for this, but you answered my last question correctly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049005/jquery-animate-background-color-not-animating?noredirect=1#comment31647804_21049005 would you like to repost your answer?

Comment: I might as well clarify the point: Once a case has evaluated to true, that's it. No more cases are checked, just all the statements executed until the end: i.e. a "break;" instruction or if the switch is terminated.

Comment: other examples [here in MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: Linters often complain when using fall-through as the fall-through can happen due to lack of a break. The recommended approach would be to create a function that would be called by both cases

Answer (score 148):

Since the other answers explained how to do it without actually explaining why it works:

When the `switch` executes, it finds the first matching `case` statement and then executes each line of code after the switch until it hits either a `break` statement or the end of the `switch` (or a `return` statement to leave the entire containing function). When you deliberately omit the `break` so that code under the next `case` gets executed too that's called a *fall-through*. So for the OP's requirement:

```
switch (pageid) {
   case "listing-page":
   case "home-page":
      alert("hello");
      break;

   case "details-page":
      alert("goodbye");
      break;
}
```

Forgetting to include `break` statements is a fairly common coding mistake and is the first thing you should look for if your `switch` isn't working the way you expected. For that reason some people like to put a comment in to say "fall through" to make it clear when break statements have been omitted on purpose. I do that in the following example since it is a bit more complicated and shows how some cases can include code to execute before they fall-through:

```
switch (someVar) {
   case 1:
      someFunction();
      alert("It was 1");
      // fall through
   case 2:
      alert("The 2 case");
      // fall through
   case 3:
      // fall through
   case 4:
      // fall through
   case 5:
      alert("The 5 case");
      // fall through
   case 6:
      alert("The 6 case");
      break;

   case 7:
      alert("Something else");
      break;

   case 8:
      // fall through
   default:
      alert("The end");
      break;
}
```

You can also (optionally) include a `default` case, which will be executed if none of the other cases match - if you don't include a `default` and no cases match then nothing happens. You can (optionally) fall through to the default case.

So in my second example if `someVar` is 1 it would call `someFunction()` and then you would see four alerts as it falls through multiple cases some of which have alerts under them. Is `someVar` is 3, 4 or 5 you'd see two alerts. If `someVar` is 7 you'd see "Something else" and if it is 8 or any other value you'd see "The end".

Comment: The //fall through comment make my phpstorm stop warning me about the fall-through switch statement, thanks :)

Comment: You can use **return** instead of **break** if the switch is in a function that you call to return some object:  switch (action.type) { case ADD: { return newState; } case DELETE: { return newState; } default: { return state; } }

Answer (score 18):

You have to switch it!

```
switch (true) {
    case ( (pageid === "listing-page") || (pageid === ("home-page") ):
        alert("hello");
        break;
    case (pageid === "details-page"):
        alert("goodbye");
        break;
}
```

Comment: This method is very innovative :-) I like it for that. But, as it uses more characters than the classic "fall-through", it becomes lesser interesting :)

Comment: @AlexLaforge the most weird and ironical that in another stackouverflow question such answer was totally downvoted. But nevertheless i support this answer and agree, that's good solution for flexible conditions.

Answer (score 16):

You need to make two `case` labels.

Control will fall through from the first label to the second, so they'll both execute the same code.

Answer (score 4):

Forget `switch` and `break`, lets play with `if`. And instead of asserting

```
if(pageid === "listing-page" || pageid === "home-page")
```

lets create several arrays with cases and check it with [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
var caseA = ["listing-page", "home-page"];
var caseB = ["details-page", "case04", "case05"];

if(caseA.includes(pageid)) {
    alert("hello");
}
else if (caseB.includes(pageid)) {
    alert("goodbye");
}
else {
    alert("there is no else case");
}
```

Comment: I think this is not the best solution, specially for perfomance. The .includes is way slower than a switch case, and thus, using if/else. It is best by using the switch case with fall-through.

Answer (score 0):

## Cleaner way to do that

```
if (["listing-page", "home-page"].indexOf(pageid) > -1)
    alert("hello");

else if (["exit-page", "logout-page"].indexOf(pageid) > -1)
    alert("Good bye");
```

You can do that for multiple values with the same result

Answer (score -9):

Use commas to separate case

```
switch (pageid)
{
    case "listing-page","home-page":
        alert("hello");
        break;
    case "details-page":
        alert("goodbye");
        break;
}
```

Comment: The reason why this doesn't work is because `case "listing-page","home-page":` is equivalent to `case "home-page":` (because `"listing-page","home-page"` [is just an expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) evaluating to `"home-page"`).