# How Can I Combine Multiple Cases?

Tags: javascript, case

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript or-expression in a switch case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513585/javascript-or-expression-in-a-switch-case)

```
case 'att':
   window.location.replace('/att-Forms.htm');
   break;
case 'at&t':
   window.location.replace('/att-Forms.htm');    
   break;
```

is there a way to shorten this with some kind of "or" function?

Comment: its very simple press Caps Lock ... than type

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Combine the cases

```
case 'att':
case 'at&t':
    window.location.replace('/att-Forms.htm');    
    break;
```

Answer (score 15):

Just place `case` statements one after another:

```
case "att":
case "at&t":
    window.location.replace("/att-Forms.htm");
    break;
```

Comment: how do I carry that input into the next page's form?