# jQuery animate background color not animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

http://jsfiddle.net/leonwho/98mD2/

HTML

```
<div id="account-setup-guide">
    <div id="account_tour_info">
        <ul>
            <li class="setup_complete"><strong>1</strong> Sync!</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#account-setup-guide {
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px 30px 20px 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: auto;
    border: 5px solid orange;
    background: orange;
}
```

jQuery

```
var animateThis = function() {

    console.log('run animateThis');

    $('#account-setup-guide').stop().animate({backgroundColor: '#ffffff'}, 500);

    $('#account-setup-guide').animate({
        background: 'white'
    }, 500);
}

animateThis();
```

Not sure why this isn't working, I've used both examples above of the `.animate` but it's not working in my current jsfiddle test :(

Comment: adding jQuery UI: http://jsfiddle.net/98mD2/14/  jQuery core doesn't support animating color, jQuery UI does or jquery color plugin if you don't need all UI plugin. BTW, you could use CSS3 transition

Comment: Ah thanks man! Do you want to post this as an answer? Thought I was going crazy lol

Comment: @kei had posted answer, now deleted. I hope he'll undelete his answer so you could accept it instead

Comment: @A.Wolff do you remember how much rep he had? 14 Kei's on stack

Comment: 7,283  username kei  http://stackoverflow.com/users/747674/kei  FYI, with more than 10000 in rep, you can still see deleted answers ;)

Comment: I don't see the deleted answer :( maybe his power rep cloaks them hehe, anyways would you like to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery doesn't support animation of color, you have to include plugin which support it as `jQuery UI` or `jQuery color`:

[jQuery color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E9amG/)   (thx to kei)

Comment: Thanks, normally I use CSS for background animation, but figured I'd do this in js instead this time...