# Accepting partial strings of user input

Tags: javascript, string, input, substring

Hey guys forgive the newbie language in this question.

I'm learning JS and trying to keep my code as parsimonious as possible. Is there an easier way to allow for either a slice of a string or the entire thing?  I came up with this as a solution but I'm sure there is a much shorter way of doing this.  Thanks in advance for the help!

```
var answer = prompt("Who is your favorite Star Wars Character?", "Enter something, Rebel Scum.");

switch(answer.toLowerCase()) {
  case 'jar jar' && 'jar jar binks':
    console.log("Seriously...");
    break;
}
```

Comment: `case 'jar jar': case 'jar jar blinks':`

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513585/javascript-or-expression-in-a-switch-case

Answer (score 1):

You can not use && in switch case..
Try this
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nisr19/d85vxu8d/)

```
var answer = prompt("Who is your favorite Star Wars Character?", "Enter something, Rebel Scum.");
switch (answer.toLowerCase())
{
    case "jar jar":
    case "jar jar binks":
        alert("hello");
        break;

}
```